# Show a UI which lets the user choose which phone number to use

Tags: ios, swift, addressbookui

As far as I know one can use the AddressBookUI class to show a contacts information with the same UI as the official address book uses. Now I want to let the user choose which phone number, email ect. he wants to use in my app.

So I need a screen where his contact from the address book is shown and where he has something like a checkbooks next to the different numbers and email addresses he wants to use.

Is there an option in AddressBookUI to achieve this?

Comment: After displaying the address book, what should be able to the user to do? let's say I selected one, what's next?

Comment: The user will see the full contact which he selected. The he can select which phone numbers or email he wants to use in my app.

Comment: So, I assume that when selecting a contact, a custom scene should be displayed containing the desired information and options... You might need to check: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/addressbookui/abpeoplepickernavigationcontrollerdelegate/1614403-peoplepickernavigationcontroller